# VS2019 document(function () changes to document

Tags: html

I'm not sure what is changed(or I have a mistake), but now I don't see input events:

In code below as soon I type   `$('txtUserName')`. I expect to see evens , for example `keyUp`, but it does not show , after dot I only see document and ready.

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('txtUserName').

        });


       

     

    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            User Name: <asp:TextBox runat="server"  id="txtUser"/>

            <input type="" id="txtUserName" " />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="divOutPut"> </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that Jquery Intelisense is not working properly in aspx file in VS2019.

After some research, I installed `vquery-vsDoc Version 2.1.0 (stabled)` from nuget and now I see all of the intelisense poping up.

I only tested this in VS2019. Not sure if it works in 2022.